# Implementation restriction: FeedItem requires a filter by Id

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

When T tested with non-admin user this error occurred. Any possible solution for this ?
I have class which called by trigger. According to my functionality i have to calculate latest Activity's days since activity happened to current date. With the admin user all functionality runs successfully, but when tested with non-admin user error occurred on FeedItem's list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYBrm.png)

`

```
List<FeedItem> feeditemList =[SELECT ID, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name, ParentId, Parent.Name, Body FROM FeedItem where parentId =:oppId_Set  ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC limit 1];
        
        system.debug('$$$ feeditemList: '+ feeditemList);
        //FeedItem
        for(FeedItem fi : feeditemList) {
            if(!feeditemList.isEmpty())
            {
                if(fi.CreatedDate<>Null)
                {
                    latestFeeditemDate =fi.CreatedDate;
                    system.debug('latestFeeditemDate in feeditem loop'+latestFeeditemDate);                    
                }
            }
        }
```

`
Any Possible Solution for this.